# Haskell CPS Programming Style Problem

Tags: haskell, continuations

here is a function multiplies the elements in a list using CPS style

```
mlist xx k = aux xx k
  where aux [] nk = nk 1
    aux (0:xs) nk = k 0
    aux (x:xs) nk = aux xs $ \v -> mul x v nk
```

what if I change the **'k' to 'nk'** in the expression **aux (0:xs) nk = k 0**, whats the difference between the two ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`k` is always the original continuation passed to `mlist` whereas for the list [1, 0] `nk` in that case will be `\v -> mul 1 v k` (from third case of `aux`).

If we assume `mul` is defined as `mul x y k = k $ x*y`, this doesn't make a practical difference since `y` will always be 0. But the actual method of arriving at that result is different (barring possible optimizations by the compiler).

Comment: IME, using k instead of passing a new continuation often allows for significant compiler optimizations.  I have not yet seen a case where  using 'k' isn't at least as efficient as 'nk', and it's often measurably faster.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that the original definition "short circuits" any built-up multiplications passed by tail call applications, while the changed expression only short-circuits testing the values - it keeps the built-up "version" of the continuation function.